# FAB background tint does not change in fragment but changes in activity?

Tags: android, user-interface, floating-action-button

I had this fab in my activity previously and it was working fine, but now I have shifted my code from activity to a fragment. Now I have 3 Fabs in my layout and I cannot change the background color or any of them. Here is my code. Am I doing something wrong or what's the mistake? Any help would be appreciated?

P.S. the color of my fab buttons is the default Aqua color, not even my apps accent color, and I can see the reflected change in my layout editor but not on my device!!

```
 <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_change_map_type"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/color_accent"
        android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onClick(v)}"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_change_map_display_type"
        android:visibility="@{viewModel.routeInfoViewModel.routeInfoViewEnabledLive ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/card_gps_error"
        app:rippleColor="@color/color_accent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `app:` namespace for the `backgroundTint` property of `FloatingActionButtons`. [Material Components reference](https://material.io/develop/android/components/floating-action-button/)

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_change_map_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ...
    app:backgroundTint="@color/color_accent"
    ...
     />
```

Comment: But do you know why this android:backgroundTint worked in activity and in fragment i have to use the Material components reference ?